# Overview of relations between cryptographic primitives?

Tags: collision-resistance, pseudo-random-generator, one-way-function, commitments

Is there a web page that gives a graphical (or, alternatively, a textual) overview of **known implications and separations** between cryptographic primitives?

More specifically, I am looking for something like the following, but more comprehensive and with references to the respective works.
(The following graphic is taken from a set of slides by Danny Harnik and Moni Naor that I found on the Internet.)
[image: Cryptomania and Minicrypt]

## Update (Jan 24, 2023)

Created an interactive visualization of the relationships between cryptographic primitives and open-sourced it at https://github.com/matthiasgeihs/crypto-graph. Contributions are welcome!

Comment: Does https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39735/whats-a-cryptographic-primitive-really/52058#52058 help any...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll find it in any textbook on basics of cryptography, for example *Foundations of Cryptography* by Goldreich. I have added a figure which sums up the relationship between the primitives: arrow represent reductions (i.e. $A\rightarrow B$ means that primitive $B$ can be constructed in a black-box manner from primitive $A$) and dashed arrows represent separations (i.e. $A$--$> B$ means that primitive $B$ cannot be constructed in a black-box manner from primitive $A$). The asterisk denotes folklore results (but feel free to correct me if it is wrong).

(1. I'll add other primitives (FHE, iO...) and assumptions (Factoring, DLP...) in due course.

2. Please correct any mistakes in implications/separations or references.)

[image]

Note that this is a screenshot from an active page [Relations in Cryptography](https://cryptorelations.appspot.com/static/index.html) produced by [mti](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/39104/mti)

**Abbreviations**

1. C: Commitments
2. CFP: claw-free permutation
3. CRHF: collision-resistant hash function
4. DLP: discrete-logarithm problem
5. DS: digital signature
6. OWF: one-way function
7. OWP: one-way permutation
8. TDP: trapdoor permutation
9. OT: oblivious transfer
10. MPC: multi-party computation
11. PKE: public-key encryption
12. PRG: pseudo-random generator
13. PRF: pseudo-random function
14. PRP: pseudo-random permutation
15. SKE: symmetric-key encryption
16. UOWHF: universal one-way hash function
17. ZKP: zero-knowledge proofs for NP

**References.**

[D]: Damgård. Collision Free Hash Functions and Public Key Signature. Eurocrypt’87.

[GGM] Goldreich, Goldwasser and Micali. How to Construct Random Functions. JACM’86.

[BM] Blum and Micali. How to Generate Cryptographically Strong Sequence of Pseudorandom Bits. SIAM JoC’82.

[EGL] Even, Goldreich and Lempel. A Randomized Protocol for Signing Contracts. CACM’85.

[GMR]: Goldwasser, Micali and Rivest. A Digital Signature Scheme Secure Against Adaptive Chosen-Message Attacks. SIAM JoC’88.

[GMW1]: Goldreich, Micali and Wigderson. How to Play any Mental Game: A Completeness Theorem for Protocols with Honest Majority. STOC’87

[GMW2]: Goldreich, Micali and Wigderson. Proofs that Yield Nothing but their Validity or All Languages in NP Have Zero Knowledge Proof. FOCS’86

[H+]: Håstad, Impagliazzo, Levin and Luby. A Pseudorandom Generator from Any One-Way Function. SIAM JoC’99.

[IR] Impagliazzo and Rudich. Limits on the Provable Consequences of One-Way Permutations. STOC’89.

[LR] Luby and Rackoff. How to Construct Pseudorandom Permutations from Pseudorandom Functions. SIAM JoC’88.

[N] Naor. Bit Commitment using Pseudorandom Generator. JoC’91.

[NY] Naor and Yung. Universal One Way Hash Functions and their Cryptographic
Application. STOC’89.

[Rom] Rompel. One way Functions are Necessary and Sufficient for Secure Signatures. STOC’90.

[Rud] Rudich. PhD Thesis

[S] Simon. Finding collisions on a one-way street: Can secure hash functions be based on general assumptions? Eurocrypt’98

[Y] Yao. Theory and Applications of Trapdoor Functions . FOCS’82

---

This was the original image of the answer.

[image]

Comment: Q: Is it possible to use TikZ code here?

Comment: @biv should be able to help you with that I think

Comment: EGL actually requires an *enhanced* trapdoor permutation; see Appendix in the second volume of Goldreich's FoC.

Comment: Also [this](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/p_tdp.html).

Comment: I think it would be worth for the community to create a webpage summarizing these relations. Somewhat like the "complexity zoo" webpage. I am thinking about creating such a page. What do you think? Would that be helpful?

Comment: I would love to see something similar that covers oracles in terms of the underlying assumption (strong v. weak).

Comment: @mti: It would most certainly be helpful!

Comment: @floorcat: That too would be a good exercise.

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer I have been setting up a website for this: [Relations in Cryptography](https://www.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/~mgeihs/relations/). You may want to add it to your answer as a reference. Please also feel free to comment on it. I want to further extend it.

Comment: @mti: The website is really cool. :) 
One suggestion: you should add Wikipedia links to the nodes.

Comment: @mti [The existence of target collision resistance hash function](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55152/what-is-the-relation-between-the-existence-of-a-cryptographic-hash-function-and) is equivalent to the existence of one-way functions.

Comment: Why is not there an arrow: PRP $\rightarrow$ PRF?

Comment: It could be added, but is trivial in some sense (the same way OWPs imply OWFs).

Comment: Removed the link to the website. I just don't have enough time at the moment to fix the 'due course' bit. Will try it soon. :)

Comment: There are a lot of really important arrows missing. For example the one from CRHF to C or the one from TDP to OWP.

Comment: Is there something similar for capabilities? Like authentication, secure communication, safe remote computing, etc?

Comment: @ckamath Updated link to website: [Relations in Cryptography](https://cryptorelations.appspot.com/)

Comment: it would be great to have Abbreviations table  like the one in this post in the website as well

Comment: @mti thanks for the website.

Comment: @kelalaka Upon request via twitter, open-sourced the page at https://github.com/matthiasgeihs/crypto-graph. Contributions are welcome :)