# What is the relation between the existence of a cryptographic hash function and the existence of a PRG?

Tags: hash, pseudo-random-generator

Does the existence of a PRF/PRG/one way function imply the existence of a hash function? I did not find a proof of the existence of a cryptographic hash function, so I want to know whether it is based the same axiom (the PRG axiom)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a black-box separation between one-way functions and collision resistant hash functions. This was proven at Eurocrypt 1998 by Dan Simon, in the paper entitled [Finding collisions on a one-way street: Can secure hash functions be based on general assumptions?](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBFb0054137.pdf). Of course, this doesn't mean that it's not possible using non-black-box reductions, but no one knows how to do this.

Answer (score 7):

To complement [Yehuda Lindell's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/55157/48790), if you need a property weaker than collision resistance (e.g. target collision resistance), then the existence of such hash function is equivalent to the existence of one-way functions, which is [equivalent to the existence of prgs](https://www.nada.kth.se/~johanh/prgfromowf.pdf).