# Security assumption: Where is an assumption from (who provides and formalizes it)?

Tags: provable-security, reference-request

Is there a list of all the (most) assumptions (such as RSA and DDH assumptions) used in cryptography and the corresponding properties?

Comment: We'll need a defined scope for this, otherwise, the list will grow infinitely. My suggestion would be key-establishment and digital signature schemes, and symmetric-key encryption and hash algorithms used in major Internet protocols such as SSH, SSL/TLS, QUIC, IPSec, IKE. If you think this is a good idea, please consider amending your post accordingly.

Comment: Maybe this [post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52325/overview-of-relations-between-cryptographic-primitives) answers your question